# How might I merge two shapes?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to model a chess set. I want the rectangley shape to to be like a circle at the bottom.

Here's an image to help explain:

[image]

Comment: i am really curious what you mean... ;) but i hope i did understand you right

Comment: Good luck with the knight. :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this case, the [grid fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html#grid-fill) operator would be most useful (as would using less geometry). To align the fill correctly, use the redo panel with <kbd>F9</kbd> and adjust the *offset* as seen in the below gif.

After filling, you may press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select the cube, TAB -> subdivide

[image]

[image]

select the lower vertices:

[image]

turn on proportional editing

press s to scale

[image]

[image]

F3 -> to sphere -> Factor 1

G Z move down as you like